# Predictions using Tensorflow, MNIST

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I'm trying to create a deep NN for mnist. I understand the training part but I've very confused about how to make actual predictions after restoring a pre-trained model. Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('tmp/data/', one_hot=True)

n_nodes_hl1 = n_nodes_hl2 = n_nodes_hl3 = 500
n_classes, batch_size = 10, 100

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

def DeepNN_model(data):

    hl1 = {
        'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),
        'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))
    }

    hl2 = {
        'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
        'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))
    }

    hl3 = {
        'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
        'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))
    }

    output_layer = {
        'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
        'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
    }

    # (input * weights) + biases

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hl1['weights']), hl1['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hl2['weights']), hl2['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hl3['weights']), hl3['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']), output_layer['biases'])

    return output

def train_DeepNN(x):

    # treat these like defs
    prediction = DeepNN_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    # feedforward + backprop
    n_epochs = 10

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(n_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                _, cost_value = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += cost_value

            print('Epoch: ', epoch + 1, ' Loss: ', epoch_loss)

        # 'saver' must be created after the variables that you want to save (or restore)
        tf.add_to_collection('x', x)
        tf.add_to_collection('preds', prediction)
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.save(sess, 'tmp/mnist_DeepNN.ckpt')

        # treat these like defs too; too high level, almost weird, still cool
        correctness = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correctness, tf.float32))

        print('Accuracy: ', 100*accuracy.eval({
            x: mnist.test.images,
            y: mnist.test.labels
            }))

def predict(x_test):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('tmp/mnist_DeepNN.ckpt.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./tmp/'))

        x = tf.get_collection('x')[0]
        prediction = tf.get_collection('preds')[0]
        print('DeepNN restored!')

        predict = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: x_test})
        print(predict)
        print(tf.argmax(predict, 1), tf.argmax(mnist.test.labels, 1))

#train_DeepNN(x)
predict(mnist.test.images)
```

I'm getting the following error in the `predict()` function:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback):
>   You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float and shape [?,784]

I think I'm not understanding what to pass in `sess.run()`. I've been googling for the past three hours and I'm not finding anything.

What's wrong with my `predict()` function?